# Gnome3 Hot-corner/super-key behaviour now zooms out displays, how to revert behaviour

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome3, window-manager

So previously, my hot-corner in Gnome 3 gave me some options of programs to open (same behavior for the super key). I'm on two monitors. Now it zooms out both screens (slowly and with lag on good hardware) and generally is useless.

I'm on arch and recently upgraded the system with `pacman -Syu`.

`cat /var/log/pacman.log | grep "gnome"` gives me relevantly:

```
[2021-04-10T10:50:25+0200] [ALPM] upgraded gnome-session (3.38.0+14+g87d92fec-1 -> 40beta+4+gd44888fb-1)
[2021-04-10T10:50:25+0200] [ALPM] upgraded gnome-settings-daemon (3.38.1-1 -> 40.0-1)
[2021-04-10T10:50:25+0200] [ALPM] upgraded gnome-shell (1:3.38.4-1 -> 1:40.0-1)
[2021-04-10T10:50:25+0200] [ALPM] upgraded gnome-control-center (3.38.5-1 -> 40.0-1)
[2021-04-10T10:50:25+0200] [ALPM] upgraded gnome-calendar (3.38.2-1 -> 40.0-1)
[2021-04-10T10:50:25+0200] [ALPM] upgraded gnome-clocks (40.0-1 -> 40.0-2)
[2021-04-10T10:50:25+0200] [ALPM] upgraded gnome-contacts (3.38.1-1 -> 40.0-1)
[2021-04-10T10:50:25+0200] [ALPM] upgraded gnome-shell-extensions (3.38.2-1 -> 40.0-1)
[2021-04-10T10:50:25+0200] [ALPM] upgraded gnome-weather (3.36.1-1 -> 40.0-1)
```

So far I've been unable to pinpoint further where the change happened.

Answer (score 2):

This change happened with gnome 40 and arch was quick to adapt. The change is described [here](https://blogs.gnome.org/shell-dev/2021/02/23/gnome-shell-40-and-multi-monitor/). Solution is to rollback or change windows manager. It now takes an extra click on the other end of the screen to scroll through the program options.

Comment: I want to remember you, GNOME has a glowing extension framework, so it's likely in the near future to have some extensions which fit your needs